# Showing multiple AlertDialogs

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am relatively new to Android/Java. Thanks to Stack Overflow, I was able to learn a lot from the questions asked here. However, I am now stuck on this problem.

I have a password input `AlertDialog` that pops up when we start the app. It reads the password from the `EditText` and compare this with the one stored in a file. I needed an extra `AlertDialog` which show up when an invalid/wrong password is provided. This also I implemented.

Now, this second dialog has two buttons - <kbd>Reset</kbd> and <kbd>Retry</kbd>. I want the activity to show the first dialog again when we click <kbd>Retry</kbd>. This is where I am clueless. If anyone can provide a working solution and a little explanation, I will be very obliged.

Here is my code:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View passView = li.inflate(R.layout.authdialog, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

// set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
alertDialogBuilder.setView(passView);

final EditText passInput = (EditText) passView.findViewById(
        R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
final TextView txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String data = "";
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("authfile");

                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                    data = br.readLine();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (data.toString().equals(
                        passInput.getText().toString())) {
                    txtv.setText("You Have Logged in");
                } else {
                    LayoutInflater ln = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    View invalidView = ln.inflate(R.layout.invdialog,
                            null);
                    AlertDialog.Builder invalidDialogBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    invalidDialogBuild.setView(invalidView);

                    // set dialog message
                    invalidDialogBuild
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton(
                                    "Retry",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton(
                                    "Reset",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });

                    dialog.cancel();

                    AlertDialog invalidDialog = invalidDialogBuild
                            .create();

                    // show it
                    invalidDialog.show();
                }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I know you already have the dialogs partly working. But I actually find it a better user experience to not use dialogs for that purpose. Instead I might have my login screen `Activity` with `EditView` for User name and password, Submit button etc. And I also have a `TextView` Message which I update to red and a message (using `theTextView.setText("")` if the person fails to login. This way your not poping up anything just simply changing a message text to alert the user their username is invalid

Comment: Actually this is a one person only app, where they need not the username but just  the password. And I need that to be done on the splash screen instead after showing the screen for 2 sec or less the password must be asked. You approach can be achieved through the dialog as well by just changing the textview that is on top instead of poping a new message. But then there will be no reset option. Can I have three buttons in an alert dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two separate method of your dialogs and call them as i have done in below code check out.

> ```
>  private void dialogShow()
> {
>     LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
>     View passView = li.inflate(R.layout.authdialog, null);
>     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
>     // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
>     alertDialogBuilder.setView(passView);
>     final EditText passInput = (EditText) passView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
>     final TextView txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
>     // set dialog message
>     alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
>             .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
>             {
>             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
>             {
>                 String data = "";
>                 try
>                 {
>             FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("authfile");                            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
>                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
>                 data = br.readLine();
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception e)
>                 {
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>             if (data.toString().equals(passInput.getText().toString()))
>                     {
>                         txtv.setText("You Have Logged in");
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                     RetryDialog();//Call the dialog of retry
>                     }
>                 }
>             }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
>             {
>                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
>                 {
>                     dialog.cancel();
>                 }
>             });
>     // create alert dialog
>     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
>     // show it
>     alertDialog.show();
> }
> ```

```
    //Shows the Retry Dialog 
private void RetryDialog()
{
     LayoutInflater ln = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     View invalidView = ln.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder invalidDialogBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    // invalidDialogBuild.setView(invalidView);
    // set dialog message
    invalidDialogBuild.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    dialogShow();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Reset", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

    AlertDialog invalidDialog = invalidDialogBuild.create();
    // show it
    invalidDialog.show();

}
```

**EDITED:**

Dialog with the ThreeButtons.

> ```
>   /**
>  * This is method to display dialog with three
>  * button("Yes, No and Cancel button")
>  */
> public void showThreeButtonDialog()
> {
>     private AlertDialog m_alertDialog;
>     private AlertDialog.Builder m_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
>     m_builder.setTitle("Title Text");
>     m_builder.setMessage("Dialog Message");
>     m_builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(DialogInterface p_dialog, int p_which)
>         {
>             Toast.makeText(AlertDialogActivity.this, "Press Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     });
>     m_builder.setNeutralButton("No"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(DialogInterface p_dialog, int p_which)
>         {
>             Toast.makeText(AlertDialogActivity.this, "Press No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     });
>     m_builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(DialogInterface p_dialog, int p_which)
>         {
>             Toast.makeText(AlertDialogActivity.this, "Press Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     });
>     m_alertDialog = m_builder.create();
>     m_alertDialog.show();
> }
> ```

Comment: One more query, is it possible to have 3 buttons in alertDialog.

Comment: Check out i have updated my answer for the ThreeButtons dialog.

Comment: Thanks again :D What I'd do without StackExchange

Comment: I think in RetryDialog() under .setPositive, we should palce dialog.cancel(); before dialogShow();

Answer (score 1):

Grishu beat me to it, mine is at least shorter...

```
private void showLoginDialog(final Context context) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View passView = li.inflate(R.layout.authdialog, null);
    final EditText passInput = (EditText) passView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
    final TextView txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(passView)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String data = "";
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("authfile");
                        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                    data = br.readLine();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (data.toString().equals(passInput.getText().toString())) {
                    txtv.setText("You Have Logged in");
                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    showInvalidDialog(context);
                }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .show();
}

private void showInvalidDialog(final Context context) {
    LayoutInflater ln = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View invalidView = ln.inflate(R.layout.invdialog, null);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(invalidView)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                showLoginDialog(context);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Reset", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .show();
}
```

Explanation: move the code for the two dialogs into separate methods which can call each other. Make consequent use of the builder pattern to keep the code short and elegant. Use dialog.dismiss() instead of dialog.cancel() unless you want a potential OnCancelListener to be called.